# Bootstrap Navbar (affixed) Dynamic Width

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am having an issue getting an affixed bootstrap navbar to adjust it's width properly when the page is scrolled.

I would either like the navbar to maintain the width inside of its containing element when the page scrolls OR take the full width of the page (starting from left to right)

what am I doing wrong, or what do I need to do?

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/btckkdkk/12/

```
        <div class="container">
        <div id="renderbody">
<div id="renderbody-inner">
 <nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation" data-spy="affix" data-offset-top="100" style="margin-bottom:5px">
        <div class="col-sm-12">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle navbar-toggle-sm navbar-left" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#storysubmit-navbar">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <form action="#" class="navbar-form navbar-form-custom navbar-left" role="search" id="searchForm" data-results-target="#storyList">

                <div class="input-group">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" placeholder="Search" name="searchTerms" id="searchTerms" />
                    <div class="input-group-btn">
                        <div class="btn-group">
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-sm btn-default"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></i></button>                           
                        </div>
                        <a href="#" class="btn btn-sm btn-link" style="margin-right:30px">Advanced</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>
            <div class="navbar-form navbar-right collapse navbar-collapse" style="padding-right: 15px; padding-left: 15px; margin-right:0" id="storysubmit-navbar">
                <a href="#" class="btn btn-default btn-sm">
                    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil margin-right-5" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                    Submit
                </a>
            </div>          
        </div>

    </nav>
<div style="height:500px; background-color:darkgray;">
</div>
<div style="height:500px; background-color:lightgray;">
</div>
<div style="height:500px; background-color:darkgray;">
</div>
<div style="height:500px; background-color:lightgray;">
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Do you mean something like this: https://jsfiddle.net/btckkdkk/7/

Comment: Your #renderbody-inner css style set the width to 90%...and the navbar is inside, so it will never be 100% of the page width...

Comment: @TeutaKoraqi Oh dear.. yes just like that.I'm embarassed I didnt think, to just match the width ofthe #renderbody-inner css. Thank you for pointing that out though! Do you know why the navbar flows outside its container if I set the width to 100% though? https://jsfiddle.net/btckkdkk/8/

Comment: @TeutaKoraqi also if you want to add your comment as an answer, i will mark it as the answer. Thank you :)

Comment: @TeutaKoraqi actually this isnt working in my actual project. I'm going to edit my OP js fiddle, to more accurately mirror my actual project

Comment: @Michael, ok! Then, I will check it out what is going wrong :)

Comment: @TeutaKoraqi Okay, I have updated the JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/btckkdkk/12/

Comment: @Michael, for your question that navbar flows outside if you set width to 100%, is because parent element has width:90%

Comment: @TeutaKoraqi I would have figured that the child would become 100% of the (90%) parent.

Comment: Yes, but in this case you have position fixed  to .affix class, that's why!

Comment: Here is the the final edit: https://jsfiddle.net/btckkdkk/13/, good luck! :)

Comment: @TeutaKoraqi I dont think you got the latest fiddle.. It has a container and renderbody div around my original html. https://jsfiddle.net/btckkdkk/12/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## How to control the width of the fixed navbar

[The Affix plugin](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#affix) controls the behaviour of the Navbar by adding or removing of the `.affix` class. This class applies the `position: fixed;` property. So you can use special properties to control the width of your Navbar:

- [`top`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/top)
- [`bottom`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/bottom)
- [`left`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/left)
- [`right`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/right)

> For absolutely positioned elements (those with `position: absolute` or `position: fixed`), it specifies the distance between the margin edge of the element and the edge of its containing block.
>
> For relatively positioned elements (those with `position: relative`), it specifies the amount the element is moved below its normal position.

When Navbar is `fixed` position, its position is calculated relative to the browser window.

---

### 100% of the window

I've added this CSS to your https://jsfiddle.net/btckkdkk/8/:

```
.navbar.affix {
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: auto;
}
```

This code stretches the Navbar between the left and right edges of the window.

Check the result: https://jsfiddle.net/glebkema/essb11a1/

---

### The width of the parent block

You need to calculate the width and position of the panel in relation to the browser window. Then you will be able to simulate the position of the panel in a particular block.

You can set properties of the Navbar for the each [width of the container](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-options) by media-queries. The formula is

```
90% * (width of the container - 2 * padding of the container)
```

So the code is

```
.navbar.affix {
  left:  calc(15px + 5%);
  right: calc(15px + 5%);
  width: auto;
}
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .navbar.affix {
    left: 50%;
    right: auto;
    width: 648px;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
  }
}
@media (min-width: 992px) {
  .navbar.affix {
    width: 846px;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 1200px) {
  .navbar.affix {
    width: 1026px;
  }
}
```

Check the result: https://jsfiddle.net/glebkema/jo06z06n/

Comment: Thanks! that works. What is the left: 0; actually doing?

So this works for getting full page width, do you have any ideas for the other option of maintaining full width inside of the parent element?

Comment: @Michael The `.navbar.affix` uses `fixed` position, The `left` propety specifies the distance between the left margin edge of the element and the left edge of its containing block.

Comment: @Michael I addded second solution and some links/ Please chack my answer again.

Comment: Thank you, that second solution does seem a bit cleaner, and answers my question. Still,  I am curious, is there any way to maintain the 90% width inside of the parent element. For example, when you scroll. the width of the navbar doesnt appear to change at all?

Comment: @Michael  You need to calculate the width and position of the panel in relation to the browser window.. Then  you will be able to simulate the position of the panel in a particular block.

Comment: @Michael I completely rewrote the answer. Please check the solution for dynamic width of the Navbar.

Comment: Fantastic answer! thank you so much for all the clarification and examples. This is perfect!